# localstorage.getItem shows only one data although there is more than one data in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

Although more than one data is stored in the array item array, it shows only the most recently added data. What could be the reason for this?
Thank you in advance for your support

```
    // List items
    const array_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array_item") || "[]");

    array_item.forEach(function(item,index,array){
        const output = '<div class="bg-card p-2" style="font-size:14px;"><div class="container"><strong>Okunmadı olarak işaretlediğin makale:</strong> <a href="<?=PROOT?>home/details/'+item.sef_link +'">'+item.title+'</a></div></div>';
        console.log(array);
        document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML = output;
    });
```

Comment: You are replacing the content each time rather than appending to it!

Comment: I am not doing anything to change it. I'm just trying to pull the data in the array item array. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: `document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML = output` replaces the HTML each time, rather than appending to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array_item") || "[]");

    array_item.forEach(function(item,index,array){
        const output = '<div class="bg-card p-2" style="font-size:14px;"><div class="container"><strong>Okunmadı olarak işaretlediğin makale:</strong> <a href="<?=PROOT?>home/details/'+item.sef_link +'">'+item.title+'</a></div></div>';
        console.log(array);
        document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML += output;
    });
```

Comment: When I add new data, it is not seen before refreshing the page. For this; So what should I do to be displayed instantly? Do you know about this topic?